# Acces member variables in nested functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop, inheritance

I have a class which uses jQuery functions inside it's internal function.
How can I refer to the member variable inside the jQuery callback function?

See the code below:

```
    var UriParser = function(uri) {
        this._uri = uri; // let's say its http://example.com
    };

    UriParser.prototype.testAction = function() {
        $('a').on('click', function(event) {
            // I need the above this._uri here, 
            // i.e. http://example.com              
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is `this` inside the event handler does not refer the `UriParser` object, it is referring the dom element which was clicked.

One solution is to use a closure variable

```
UriParser.prototype.testAction = function () {
    var self = this;
    $('a').on('click', function (event) {
        //use self._uri
    })
}
```

another is to use [$.proxy()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.proxy/) to pass a custom execution context

```
UriParser.prototype.testAction = function () {
    $('a').on('click', $.proxy(function (event) {
        //use this._uri
    }, this))
}
```